# How to create bigrams of categorical column into separate columns?

Tags: python

So I would like to take every row and split it into bigrams to be used as columns in order to encode the original string column.

I have a dataset like this one:

| A |
| --- |
| blue |
| red |
| black |

I want my result to look like this:

| A | bl | lu | ue | re | ed | la | ac | ck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| red | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| black | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have tried spliting up A but it does not split characters.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: You say you have a dataset, but you've provided no example of what format your data is actually in, or how you read it into code. What part of the problem are you stuck on? Reading the data? Splitting it into bigrams? Counting the presence of bigrams in the original set of strings? You say you tried splitting, please share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I will try to be more specific in the future keeping in mind your points. YOLO provided me with an answer that works. Just for the record I was trying to use only something along this line "[s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), 1) if len(s[i:i+2]) == n]", I am on another machine rn so I can post it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
# sample data
f = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['blue', 'red', 'black']})

def bigram(s, n=2):
    return [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), 1) if len(s[i:i+2]) == n]

# using pandas 
f['bgm'] = f['A'].apply(bigram)
f = f.explode('bgm').reset_index(drop=True)
f = pd.crosstab(f['A'], f['bgm']).reset_index()
f.columns.name=None

print(f)

       A  ac  bl  ck  ed  la  lu  re  ue
0  black   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
1   blue   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
2    red   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
```